# How to wget files from all grandchild directories

Tags: bash, terminal, wget

I have a website: http://www.example.com/

This website has a subdirectory: http://www.example.com/images/

This subdirectory contains numerous subdirectories with images inside of them:

- http://www.example.com/images/01

  - http://www.example.com/images/01/img1.png
  - http://www.example.com/images/01/img2.png
  - http://www.example.com/images/01/img3.png
- http://www.example.com/images/02

  - http://www.example.com/images/02/img1.png
  - http://www.example.com/images/03/img2.png
  - http://www.example.com/images/04/img3.png
- http://www.example.com/images/03

  - etc.

When I try `wget` from the `images` directory, it downloads each directory (`01/`,`02/`, etc) and an `index.html` inside of each one. It doesn't download any of the images. e.g.

`wget -r http://www.example.com/images/` <- doesn't download pngs

`wget -r http://www.example.com/images/01/` <- does download pngs

How can I use `wget` to download all the `png`s from all the subdirectories of the `images/` directory without going through each subdirectory (01/,02/,03/, etc.) one by one?

Comment: Yep that helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get to see [`man wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) to look up for options as you requested. With a quick lookup I found these,

```
-A acclist --accept acclist         
       Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to
       accept or reject.

--no-directories
       Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.
       With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, 
       without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the filenames will get extensions .n).

Recursive Retrieval Options
-r
--recursive
       Turn on recursive retrieving. The default maximum depth is 5.
```

combining these together you can put together a command as

```
wget -nd -r -A png http://www.example.com/images/
```